# The API token generated in HackerOne isn't working When H1 is configured with SAML 2.0

Tags: saml-2.0

The API token generated in HackerOne isn't working When HackerOne is configured with SAML 2.0.
I think it's because it's configured with SAML. It worked before.

Somebody knows/handled this issue with SAML???

It worked before